# Audio driver not working in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, audio, drivers, bsod

I just re-installed Windows 10 completely. Formatted my whole HDD. Now the problem is my PC isn't recognizing any audio device. It isn't even recognizing blue-tooth and wireless. Now I have got myself a USB wireless adapter.

*The main problem is about Audio.*

I tried to install driver, then I saw there wasn't even a **Sound,Audio and Game Controllers**. So tried to solve that. There is found realtek. But it crashed during that coping or downloading screen. So I went to advanced mode and tried to add that. Now it went into **BSOD**, as there was no restoration point Windows couldn't start again. Well, I waited for a long. Then I restarted, still **BSOD**. I installed again. Now there is no audio driver and I *can't even find realtek on the list*.

I connected a speaker with intention that after plugging in devices drivers get installed, but no luck.

Here is snap of no realtek found and no Audio output is installed :

[image: no realtek found and no Audio output is installed]

Device configuration :

```
ASUS X-540LJ
Version 1809(OS build 17763.529)
```

Comment: Before any driver can be installed, Windows should see/find a hardware device itself. In Device Manager, you should see either an "Unknown device" or a device with some generic name, marked with a problem indicator. Does Windows show a problematic audio device in Device Manager?

Comment: No, there isn't any

Comment: This might me if Windows didn't install the proper enumerator for HD audio bus.

Try to install the dedicated driver from ASUS site, as described below.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an audio driver for your computer at
[Asus Product Support for X540LJ](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X540LJ/HelpDesk_Download/).

The direct download link is : [audio driver](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/DriversForWin10/Audio/Audio_Realtek_Win10_64_VER6018564_Logo.zip).

Unzip the driver (two unzips are required), run `setup.exe`, then reboot.

If this does not help, tell us what you see in Device Manager under
"Sound" and also under "Other devices". A screenshot would be best.

Comment: I tried that before and now again. It installs and reboots. Then nothing happens..

Comment: Here is a screen-shot of [Device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFIsG.png). No audio, no other device.

Comment: Here is a screen-shot of [Other Device under device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYSAw.png). I'm also adding this because some solutions said that - `Intel HD Sound ...` will be there and after another reboot , everything will be fine. But no hope here.

Comment: True, no sound devices. Your second screenshot if of "**System** devices" and not "**Other** devices".

Comment: There is not even a **Other Device**

Comment: I don't know why you re-installed Windows 10, but you should have taken precautions and backups, which is now too late. The only thing I can think of is to re-install Windows, in case something just went wrong. If this doesn't help, then the explanation might be anything, even hardware.

Comment: I format whole HDD and setup Windows , at least once a year, or twice. Once if before renewing anti-virus...

Comment: That's overdoing it. But if you wish to do that, before you should backup your drivers and take a backup image of the disk, so you can go back if something goes wrong. Question: Are you using the same Windows 10 installation every time, or have you this time used a newer one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94706/discussion-between-maifee-ul-asad-and-harrymc).

Comment: If this has worked for you before, use a previous ISO which worked and save the audio driver using a [driver backup product](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-driver-backup.htm).

Comment: Those are gone during purging HDD

Comment: You can download older versions from [windowsiso.net](http://windowsiso.net/windows-10-iso/), see on top under the menu "Windows 10 ISO".